# I need Difference between the VERY LAST values and the 2nd LAST values for each record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two `table_One` and `Table_Two` for each client the `very 1st Record goes into Table_One` There after `any more records for that client goes into Table_Two`.
Now I want the `Difference between the very last record and the 2nd last record` added for that client. say `X` is the very last value added for the client and `Y` is the 2nd last value added for the client.
 I want the Value `X - Y = value in my result set`.  
 I have attached a screen shot of the tables and desired result set.[image]

---

"Every Client will have a record in Table_One but may or may not have a record in Table_Two , Only the very 1st record goes into Table_One"
"If the very last two records are both in Table_Two then I need the Difference between them values."

my limitations are I cannot create a stored procedure as this query is being plugged into a 3rd party software and I can only execute ah-hoc sql there or UDFs but no stored procedures :(.

Comment: 78 minus 33  = 45,    not minus 45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first put all records in one result (using a cte)

then construct query by joining this to original table1, twice

```
with combined (clientid, date, column3) as
(select clientid, date, column3 from table1
 union all
select clientid, date, column3 from table2)
select t1.clientid, t1.column1, t1.column2, 
       l.column3-nl.column3   
from table1 t1
  join combined l  -- the last record
     on l.clientid = t1.clientid
       and l.date = (select max(date) 
                     from combined 
                     where clientid = t1.clientid)
  join combined nl -- the next to last record
     on nl.clientid = t1.clientid
       and nl.date = (select max(date) 
                     from combined 
                     where clientid = t1.clientid
                        and date < l.date)
```

Comment: You have absolutely nailed it Charles I wish I could give you 100 ups for this answer thank very very much Charles you are an ACE :) sir.

Comment: Hi Charles say if table two has multiple records for each client and in CTE I have filtered all the records for just one client now I want Differeces between the record and the last record added for the client. Could you please advise somehting.... In result set I will have all the records returned for a client and difference in the values from the last record.